# Closed form for $\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1-z^{2^n})$

Tags: power-series, infinite-product

Is there a closed form for the product $$f(z) = \prod_{n=0}^\infty 1-z^{2^n}$$
either as a formal power series or as an analytic function in the disk $|z| < 1$? It's not hard to see that Taylor series coefficients of $f$ about 0 are all $\pm 1$: 
$$f(z) = 1 - z - z^2 + z^3 - z^4 + z^5 + z^6 - z^7 + \dotsb$$
and that they form a pattern in blocks, so to speak: 
$$+- \quad\to\quad +--+ \quad\to\quad +--+-++- \quad\to\quad \dotsb$$
But I don't know much else. I came across this infinite product when I incorrectly transcribed an exercise from a book, wasting a good deal of time before returning to the book to ask it, "are you sure?". (The exercise was to prove that $\prod_{n=0}^\infty 1 + z^{2^n} = (1-z)^{-1}$, which is easy.)

Comment: Probably not. The coefficients of this thing are recording whether the binary expansion of a number has an even or odd number of $1$s. The inverse of this thing is a generating function describing ways to write a number as a sum of (not necessarily distinct) powers of $2$.

Comment: No, there is no known closed form for $f(z).$

Comment: A good keyword for further search is "Thue-Morse sequence". For $z=1/2$ it has been proven that the value is transcendental.

Comment: In general, $$\prod_{n\ge0}(1+az^{2^n})=\sum_{n\ge0}a^{w_2(n)}z^n,$$ where $$w_2(n)=n-\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \right\rfloor$$ is the number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting my comment from 2016 into an answer, with elaborations:

The coefficients of $z^n$ in $f(z)$ is $-1$ to the power of the number of $1$s in the binary expansion of $n$; this is a slight variant of the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) with $1$ and $-1$ instead of $0$ and $1$ ([A106400](http://oeis.org/A106400) on the OEIS). The coefficient is $1$ if $n$ is "evil" (has an even number of $1$s; [A001969](http://oeis.org/A001969) on the OEIS) and $-1$ if $n$ is "odious" (has an odd number of $1$s; [A000069](http://oeis.org/A000069) on the OEIS). The reciprocal

$$\frac{1}{f(z)} = \prod_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{1 - z^{2^{n}}}$$

is the generating function for the sequence $c_n$ counting the number of partitions of $n$ into powers of $2$, which is [A018819](http://oeis.org/A018819) on the OEIS. $c_{2n}$ is [A000123](http://oeis.org/A000123) on the OEIS because $c_{2n+1} = c_{2n}$.

According to Kachi and Tzermias' *[On the $m$-ary partition numbers](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/ab0ba342275748ebf3c76d4d4b80fcde/adm508.pdf)* this problem was first studied by Euler. Mahler showed in *[On a special functional equation](https://www.carma.edu.au/resources/mahler/docs/068.pdf)* that

$$c_n = e^{O(1)} 2^{ -{k \choose 2}} \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

where $k$ is the unique positive integer satisfying $2^{k-1} k \le n < 2^k (k+1)$. This gives $k \approx \frac{W(n \log 2)}{\log 2}$ where $W(x) \sim \log x$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which lets us write down an asymptotic for the logarithm of $c_n$ the leading term of which is

$$\log c_n \sim \frac{(\log n)^2}{2 \log 2}.$$

de Brujin's *[On Mahler's partition problem](https://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00018536.pdf)* analyzes the asymptotics more precisely.

These asymptotics imply that $c_n$ grows faster than polynomially but slower than exponentially and so rule out $f(z)$ having a particularly simple closed form; for example it follows that $f(z)$ cannot be rational (although this has an easier proof) or more generally meromorphic or algebraic.

Comment: Why can $f(z)$ not be meromorphic?

Comment: @Zachary: the coefficients of a meromorphic power series have a growth rate determined by the pole(s) closest to the origin; if the pole closest to the origin is at $z = \lambda$ and has order $k$ then the growth rate is $Cn^{k-1} \lambda^n$, and in particular cannot be strictly between polynomial and exponential growth. Probably this argument is overkill though; I think one can show more directly that $f(z)$ has the unit circle as a natural boundary. But complex analysis is not my forte.

Comment: Thanks, Qiaochu Yuan!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for the response! I was not aware that you could determine the growth of the coefficients based on the poles closest to the origin. This is very interesting.

Comment: @Zachary: for much more on this see Flajolet and Sedgewick's *Analytic Combinatorics*, which is a real gem and legally freely available online: http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you very much for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sort of a closed form, by the standard trick of taking logs. Note that $$\log(1-z) = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}k.$$
If you take the log of your product, the coefficient of $z^k$ will be equal to $$-\sum_{m=1}^{2^{\lceil \log_2 k\rceil}} \frac{1}{m}=-H_{2^{\lceil \log_2 k\rceil}},$$ where $H_n$ are the harmonic numbers.

Comment: Not quite! $\log f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty -z^{2^nk}/k$, and every positive integer $m$ has $\nu_2(m)+1$ representations of the form $2^nk$, namely $2^0m$, $2^1m/2$, $2^2m/4$, and so on until we exhaust the number of powers of $2$ in $m$ (of which there are $\nu_2(m)$). The coefficient of $z^m$ in $\log f(z)$ is therefore $$-\frac{2^{\nu_2(m)+1}-1}{m}.$$
So, $\log f(z) = -z - \frac{3}{2}z^2 - \frac{1}{3}z^3 - \frac{7}{4}z^4 - \frac{1}{5}z^5 - \frac{1}{2}z^6 - \dotsb$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if $$f(z)=\prod_{n\ge0}(1-z^{2^n}),$$
then
$$f(z)=(1-z)f(z^2).\tag1$$
Then define the sequence $a_n$ to satisfy $$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n.$$
Then from $(1)$ we have
$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n=(1-z)\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^{2n}.$$
This is equivalent to
$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n=b_0+\sum_{n\ge1}(b_n-b_{n-1})z^n,$$
where $b_n=[2|n]\cdot a_{n/2}$, with $[2|n]=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}$ being the Iverson bracket. Since $f(0)=1$, we have $a_0=b_0=1$, and for $n\ge1$,
$$a_n=a_{n/2}[2|n]-a_{(n-1)/2}[2|n-1].\tag2$$
For $n=2k$, $$a_{2k}=a_k[2|2k]-a_{k-1/2}[2|2k-1]=a_k.$$
Similarly, for $n=2k+1$, $$a_{2k+1}=a_{k+1/2}[2|2k+1]-a_{k}[2|2k]=-a_k.$$
As you saw, it is then easy to see that $|a_k|=1$. It then follows directly that $a_{2^n}=-1$.

We can find some special cases of $a_m$ where $m=2^k$, such as
$$\begin{align}
a_{2m+1}&=1\\
a_{4m+2}&=1\\
a_{4m+3}&=-1\\
a_{8m+6}&=-1\\
a_{8m+7}&=1\\
a_{16m+14}&=1\\
a_{16m+15}&=-1\\
a_{32m+30}&=-1\\
a_{32m+31}&=1\\
&...
\end{align}$$
which all follow from $a_m=-1$.

Clearly, $a_n$ expresses *something* about the ways in which one can write $n$ as $a2^k+b$, for very specific $a,b$, but other than that, it is proving exceedingly difficult to find a general closed form for $a_n$. I doubt a closed form for $f(z)$ exists.

Comment: Take a look at my comment to the original post from 2016. $a_n$ is $-1$ to the power of the number of $1$s in the binary expansion of $n$. This follows just from expanding the infinite product directly.